# SIM800L GSM module is not working

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I'm testing SIM800L GSM module with Arduino UNO and module is blinking 3 times every 15 seconds or sometime every 45 seconds. Why this is happening?
In serial monitor it shows `Message Sent Successfully!` but I'm not getting any message.I tried with multiple numbers. Still not getting any message.

I have tested several codes which shows outputs of AT commands. Nothing was working. Power supply is 5V 5A.

```
/*    
 *   Author@ExploreEmbedded 
 *   Example to Send messages Interactively using GSM Sim800L
 *    
 *   LIBRARY CREDITS:
 *   Thanks to Cristian Steib(steibkhriz@gmail.com) for the library.
 *    
 *  
 *     
 *      PINOUT: 
 *        _____________________________
 *       |  ARDUINO UNO >>>   Sim800L  |
 *        -----------------------------
 *            GND      >>>   GND
 *        RX  10       >>>   TX    
 *        TX  11       >>>   RX
 *       RESET 2       >>>   RST 
 *                 
 *  
*/

#include <Sim800L.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //is necesary for the library!! 
Sim800L Sim800L;  //to declare the library
char text[161]=""; //buffer to store message
char number[11]=""; //phone number to send message
int cnt;
bool error; //to catch the response of sendSms

void setup(){
    Sim800L.begin(); // initializate the library. 
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

      //Read the Number
      Serial.print("\nEnter 10 digit Phone Number:");
      while(Serial.available()<=0); 
      cnt = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n',number, 11);
      number[cnt] = '\0';
      Serial.println(number);

      //clear the serial input buffer so that no typed characters are pending

      delay(1000); //delay required before clearing the input buffer
      while(Serial.available()>0) //clear buffer
      {
        Serial.read();
      }


      //Read the Message to be sent
      Serial.print("Enter Message:");
      while(Serial.available()<=0); 
      cnt = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n',text, 160);
      text[cnt] = '\0';
      Serial.println(text);
      delay(1000);

      while(Serial.available()>0) //clear buffer
      {
        Serial.read();
      }

      //Send the message and display the status
      error = Sim800L.sendSms(number,text);
      if(error)
      Serial.println("Error Sending Message");
      Serial.println("Message Sent Successfully!");


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found what's happening. Module was shutdown due to over voltage.